# qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped in docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am setting up Kafka in my local machine using docker-compose.

My machine details are:

```
macOsBigSur
Version - 11.2.3 (20D91)
Chip - Apple M1
RAM - 8 GB
```

Docker images are:

```
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.0
confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
rabbitmq:3-management
confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.0
```

Docker containers are not coming up due to **qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped** error.

*Could you please help me how to resolve this error?*

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue using M1 chip with MacOS Monterey 12.5.

After upgrading to MacOS Ventura 13.3 and selecting

> Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon

in Docker Desktop -> Settings -> Features in development, the error disappeared and everything worked fine.

[Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWk8Q.png)

Note that this option is not available on MacOS versions lower than Ventura 13, so upgrade is required.
Source: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6788

Comment: Look for it in the General tab as it's no longer in development for the latest versions of Docker Desktop.

Comment: @kszl This, I spent some time trying to find the option.

Comment: This setting is here now: https://imgur.com/a/R0tEONY

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you need to wait for docker-for-mac to use the version of qemu that supports the m1 chip.

Ref：

- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5123#issuecomment-784992589
- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5123#issuecomment-808476651

Answer (score 5):

For people using alpine. Try updating the qemu package. It worked for me.

`RUN apk add --update qemu-x86_64`

Should work for other OS as well.

Comment: adding this to my Dockerfile had not effect. Did you need to do anything else? (aside from rebuilding of course)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error `qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped error.` when using the docker image `java:8`(DEPRECATED).

But I could avoid that error by replacing docker image into `openjdk:18`.

So you may be able to avoid that error by replacing the base image you use.

By the way, I am also using `Chip - Apple M1`. But not using `Kafka`.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me after upgrading Docker Desktop to 4.11.1 (84025).
I am using M1 Chip with MacOS Monterey 12.4

Comment: Didn't worked for me